# How can I find out how big (data) the tag (NFC) size is?

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc

With Windows Phone 8 I'm trying to write data to a NFC tag.  However if the text is too big it fails (well it doesn't write but doesn't give an error either)  I'm trying to figure out how to query the tag to figure out how much data can be loaded onto it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.maxmessagebytes.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

- subscribing for a message

> ProxDevice.SubscribeForMessage("WriteableTag",
> OnTagDetect);

- receive the message

> private void OnTagDetect(ProximityDevice sender,
> ProximityMessage message)
>
> ```
> {
>
>    int writeableSize = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(message.Data.ToArray(), 0);
>
> }
> ```